# Comparing String with It's Reference by "=="

Tags: java, string, string-comparison

Recently I have seen a code like this -

```
class Test{
        public static void main(String[] args){

                String s1 = "String1"; //1
                String s2 = new String("String2"); //2

                System.out.println(s1.equals("String1"));
                System.out.println(s1=="String1"); //3

                System.out.println(s2.equals("String2")); 
                System.out.println(s2=="String2"); //4
        }
}
```

and the out put is -

```
true
true
true
false
```

So far I know, at point 1 "String1" is placed in String pool and assigned with String type reference variable s1. Isn't there any String object created?

We know a new String object is created at point 2 and at point 4 the expression (s2=="String2") evaluated to false. If a new String object is created at point 1 then how the expression at point 3 (s1=="String1") evaluated to true. And if a new object is not created at point 1 how the expression at point 3 (s1=="String1") evaluated to true?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Go through the duplicate. If you have any more questions, make sure to point out exactly where the confusion is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`==` Compares the reference of the string and is unreliable to use for value comparison. Your `s1=="String1"` I would imagine is true because you're comparing two literals, compared to the `s2` comparison of a new String object compared to a literal.